# WXPython Display Images Sometimes do not Display

Tags: python, image, wxpython

I am currently using WXPython to do a GUI which displays images.  I am currently changing the images about 1 to 2 times per second:

```
    image = image.Scale(scaledHeight, scaledWidth)
    image1 = image.ConvertToBitmap()

    # Center the image
    self.panel.bmp1 = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel, -1, image1, ((width / 2) - (image.GetWidth() / 2), (height / 2) - (image.GetHeight() / 2)), (image.GetWidth(),image.GetHeight()))
```

Only problem is periodically the image does not display.  I tried out an inefficient solution and copied the image into image1, image2, etc and displayed all of them hoping for the chances for all of them to not display to be lower.  Unfortunately, the image will still periodically not display.  Is there some sort of buffer I need to use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It would be convenient if you could provide your code snippet and some more details regarding what you are trying to achieve.

How ever I have created a small example which shows how to change/update images on a panel. The code below basically creates a random number in `myThread()` class. The number is then sent to the `gui()` class using [publisher-subscriber](http://wiki.wxpython.org/WxLibPubSub) strategy. The `changeImage()` of the `gui()` class checks if the value is less than or equal to `5`, then it will display green image on the panel named as `self.myPanel`, else if the value is greater than `5` then a blue image is displayed.

The images can be downloaded from here: [green.bmp](https://db.tt/vp3q6Vs1) [blue.bmp](https://db.tt/TiiodAmk)

**Code:** Please note that the image files should be in the same directory in which this script is located.

```
import wx
import time
from wx.lib.pubsub import setupkwargs
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub
from threading import Thread
import random

class gui(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, id, title, size=(100,100))
        self.myPanel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        image_file1 = 'green.bmp'
        image_file2 = 'blue.bmp'
        self.image1 = wx.Image(image_file1, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        self.image2 = wx.Image(image_file2, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        self.bitmap = wx.StaticBitmap(self.myPanel, -1)
        pub.subscribe(self.changeImage, 'Update')

    def changeImage(self, value):
        #To destroy any previous image on self.myPanel
        if self.bitmap:
            self.bitmap.Destroy()
        #If the value received from myThread() class is <= 5 then display the green image on myPanel
        if value <=5: 
            self.bitmap = wx.StaticBitmap(self.myPanel, -1, self.image1, (0, 0))
        #If the value received from myThread() class is > 5 then display the green image on myPanel
        else:
            self.bitmap = wx.StaticBitmap(self.myPanel, -1, self.image2, (10, 10))

class myThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        while True:
            number = random.randrange(1,10)
            wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage, 'Update', value=number)
            time.sleep(1)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = gui(parent=None, id=-1, title="Test")
    frame.Show()
    myThread()
    app.MainLoop()
```